# object Reference to list item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I have a reference to list item object, and remove that object from the the list and added it to a new list, will the reference remain:

```
Dim AL As New List(of Sample)
Dim objSample As New Sample
AL.Add(objSample)

Dim objRef As Sample = AL(0)

Dim Temp As Sample = AL(0)
AL.RemoveAt(0)

Dim AL2 As New List(of Sample)
AL2.Add(Temp)
```

Will objRef refer to AL2(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code boils down to:

```
'Dim AL As New List(Of Sample)
Dim objSample As New Sample
'AL.Add(objSample)

Dim objRef As Sample = objSample 'AL(0)

Dim Temp As Sample = objSample 'AL(0)
'AL.RemoveAt(0)

Dim AL2 As New List(Of Sample)
AL2.Add(Temp)
```

So `objSample`, `objRef`, and `Temp` are all references to the same object.

Therefore so is `AL2(0)`.